# Rspec + Capybara: controller missing, integration spec passes anyway

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd, capybara

I started a fresh new rails app (using rspec-rails 2.99 & capybara 2.3.0), and wrote a silly simple integration spec to get started with TDD:

```
# spec/integration/visit_home_page_spec.rb

require 'spec_helper'

feature "view the home page" do
  scenario "user visits home page" do
    visit root_path
    expect(page).to have_content 'Password'
  end
end
```

As expected, the test fails due to root_path being undefined - so I went ahead and:

```
# config/routes.rb

root 'users#new'
```

And here's the problem: **instead** of the spec failing due to UsersController being undefined, it's green. It appears that rspec is evaluating the error page itself, and since that page happens to contain the word "password", the spec passes.

To make sure that's what's happening, I have modified the spec to:

```
# spec/integration/visit_home_page_spec.rb

...
  expect(page).to have_content 'theresnowaythisisinthepage'
...
```

Now the test fails, but **not** because it's picking up the undefined UsersController - just because the content is not in the error page.

I've started many an app with this approach, and it's the first time I've seen rspec mistaking an error page for a valid one - **what did I break?**

I suspect my forehead will have a big hand-shaped mark when I find the answer.

--

Here's my **Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '~> 4.1.1'
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.16'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.2'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'active_model_serializers', '~> 0.8.1'
gem 'slim-rails', '~> 2.1.4'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.1.1.1'
gem 'bootstrap-generators', '~> 3.1.1.3'

group :test, :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.99'
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.3.0'
end

group :development do
  gem "better_errors"
  gem "binding_of_caller" # required by better-errors
  gem "launchy"
end

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end
```

Here's **spec_helper**

```
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }
ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false
  config.order = "random"
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!

  config.include Capybara::DSL
end
```

Comment: Maybe you can get help from here https://github.com/charliesome/better_errors/issues/304